# Converting GPUvector back to CPU vector using gpuR package

Tags: r, gpu

```
library(gpuR)

A <- seq.int(from=0, to=999)
B <- seq.int(from=1000, to=1)
gpuA <- gpuVector(A)
gpuB <- gpuVector(B)

C <- A + B
gpuC <- gpuA + gpuB
```

`gpuC` is a `gpuvector`. I want to see the output as numeric values. so I tried to convert to `cpuvector`. In  the `RCUDA` package `gathergpu()` function is there. but no similar function in the `gpuR` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the values using `[` without any arguments:

```
library(gpuR)

A <- seq.int(from=0, to=999)
B <- seq.int(from=1000, to=1)
gpuA <- gpuVector(A)
gpuB <- gpuVector(B)

C <- A + B
gpuC <- gpuA + gpuB

all.equal(C, gpuC)
#> [1] "Modes: numeric, S4"                             
#> [2] "Attributes: < target is NULL, current is list >"
#> [3] "target is numeric, current is igpuVector"
all.equal(C, gpuC[])
#> [1] TRUE
```